# Comparing spreasheet to StringValues, Find method finds some values but not others

Tags: excel, vba

I have a user form with a text box that updates a Table. User enters a value and a function tests whether the value has already been used (the value is a product number so they must be unique)

Everything seems to work fine, but for some values, although they already exist, Find can't find them. But other it finds them just fine. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

The only value that gets tested is the `Number_TextBox.Value`

```
'user form code
Private Sub Confirm_CommandButton_Click()
    
    Dim ctrl As control
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If Not ctrl.Name Like "Label*" Then
            If ctrl.Value = "" Then
                MsgBox DispMsg(3)
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If testEntry(CStr(Number_TextBox), ProductsWS.Range("A2:A" & lmaster.ListRows.Count)) = True Then
        If MsgBox(DispMsg(1), vbYesNo + vbCritical, DispMsg(2)) = vbYes Then
            GoTo Execute
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
Execute:
    Dim newrow As ListRow
    Set newrow = pmaster.ListRows.Add
    With newrow
    .Range(1) = Number_TextBox
    .Range(2) = Line_ComboBox
    .Range(3) = Name_TextBox
    .Range(4) = Name_TextBox.Value & "_" & Number_TextBox
    .Range(5) = CDbl(Yield_TextBox)
    .Range(6) = CDbl(StdBat_TextBox)
    .Range(7) = CDbl(Weight_TextBox)
    End With
    
    'Unload Me

End Sub

'test function (from another module)
Public Function testEntry(ByRef v As Variant, ByRef rng As Range) As Boolean

    Dim f As Range
    Set f = rng.Find(v, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        testEntry = True
    Else
        testEntry = False
    End If

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: What is a sample value that is not found?

Comment: Hi again @BigBen I was about to update. although called number, the values are strings since they are product IDs. For example, one is 02-121, another 02-100V. It finds 02-164  no porblem. But when it tests 02-121 it doesn't aalthough the valus is visibly in there! i've ven checked TRIM()

Comment: Hmm. And if you try to find the value manually (e.g. using Ctrl+F), it succeeds?

Comment: @BigBen I added a screenshot of the spreadsheet. It finds the first two but none of the rest. That might be a hint actually...

Comment: What does `Debug.Print lmaster.ListRows.Count` return? Note that if you're looking in a table, you can just use `lMaster.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange` to refer to the first column's data range.

Comment: @BigBen Ughh... that was it. I had the wrong list object. It works now. Sorry dude, it turned out to be something stupid and not the first time you'e helped me out with that...

Comment: "It finds the first two" was the hint indeed!

Comment: @BigBen If you're ever in Puerto Rico there will be a cold poolside beer with your name on it ;)

Comment: Ahhh ... just the thought of a cool poolside beer brings a smile to my face!